# Pattern match on any single UTF-8 character

Tags: utf-8, binary, pattern-matching, elixir

I would like to have a function clause that matches any single UTF-8 character.

I can match on specific characters like this

```
def foo("a") do
  "It's an a"
end
```

But I cannot determine if it possible to do the same for *any* single UTF8 character.

My current solution is to split the string to a char list and pattern match on that, but I was curious if I could skip that step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
def char?(<<c::utf8>>), do: true
def char?(_), do: false
```

Note that this only matches a binary with a single character, to match on the next character in a string, you can just do:

```
def char?(<<c::utf8, _rest::binary>>), do: true
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the Regex docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#module-modifiers):

> The modifiers available when creating a Regex are: ...
>
> - `unicode` (u) - enables Unicode specific patterns like `\p` and changes modifiers like `\w`, `\W`, `\s` and friends to also match on Unicode. It expects valid Unicode strings to be given on match
> - `dotall` (s) - causes dot to match newlines and also set newline to anycrlf; the new line setting can be overridden by setting `(*CR)` or `(*LF)` or `(*CRLF)` or `(*ANY)` according to `:re` documentation

So you might try:
~r/./us

From http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html

```
In Elixir, the word string means a UTF-8 binary and there is a String module that works on such data
```

So I think you should be good to go.

Comment: The Regex solution is ok but we typically avoid them in Elixir, specially when binary pattern matching would suffice. :)

Comment: @JoséValim could you tell me (or point to a reference of) why the Regex solution should be avoided? It's important to me since I'm a new learner of Elixir.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

```
for <<char <- "abc">> do
  def foo(unquote(<<char>>)), do: "It's an #{unquote(<<char>>)}"
end
```

Take a look at https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/3eb938a0ba7db5c6cc13d390e6242f66fdc9ef00/lib/elixir/unicode/unicode.ex#L48-L52 You can on compile time generate function for each character in binary (`"abc"` in my example). It's how Elixir unicode support works, check out whole module to better understand.

Comment: It doesn't seem like he really needs to generate those at compile time. He can always match on it dynamically as per @bitwalker answer.

Comment: Totally agree, I understand question differently. I thought @lpil needs some particular chars.